# converting image into byte[] asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, binaryreader

I need to store the image in my database in `byte[]`

I am sending the image from `Javascript` to `mvc controller` using ajax

In my javascript

```
var files = $("#MyImage").get(0).files;
formData.append('files', files);
```

in my MVC Controller

```
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
{
        fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
}
```

Is it a correct way to store the image or I am doing this wrong?

please suggest

Comment: Can you show the code how you pass the image from view to controller?

Comment: Use this code, perhaps it might be helpful **https://stackoverflow.com/a/3947318/6124847**

Comment: Easy way to determine if it is a right way: Do you receive the image as a byte array in your database? Then Yes. If Not. Debug and then tell us where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post `HttpPostedFileBase` on your razor.

```
if (upload != null)
{
    using (var inputStream = upload.InputStream)
    {
        var memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
        if (memoryStream == null)
        {
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }
        var data = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

The method signature should be like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
}
```

And your razor side:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Foo", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```